# Can you really use "leisure centre" in this context?

Tags: word-usage, word-request

What do you call the activity/place that kids go to after school while their parents are at work? Like a day-care centre, only for slightly older kids? A friend suggested "leisure centre", but to me, that's not the same thing at all... Or am I wrong about this? Would you use leisure centre for this? If not, what would you use?

Thank you!

Comment: "After-school club" at my kids' school.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian Thank you! Do you agree that "leisure centre" doesn't work?

Comment: It doesn't work at *all*. They'd go to a leisure centre to swim, have a sauna, play squash or roll around in cages full of plastic balls! Schools just use one of the classrooms and give the children Plasticene! Going to the leisure centre is a treat, for weekends mostly. [In the UK, at least.]

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure what you men by older kids in your context. If they are old enough to go to school, they definitely are eligible for day-care centres.

> Day-care centre, also called day nursery, nursery school, or crèche (French: “crib”), institution that provides supervision and care of infants and young children during the daytime, particularly so that their parents can hold jobs. [Source](https://www.britannica.com/topic/day-care-center)

As you can see in the quoted text, they can be alternatively called as a **nursery**, **nursery school** or a **child-care centre**. But these usages would not mean that they are going there after school. Usually nursery school is attended before going to an actual school (more like a preschool you can say).

If they are visiting the place after school hours, they maybe called **after-school care**. These are applicable in the case of both primary schools and secondary schools.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/After-school_activity):

> Some programs are run by a primary or secondary school, while others are run by externally funded non-profit or commercial organizations. After-school youth programs can occur inside a school building or elsewhere in the community, for instance at a community center, church, library, or park.

**Leisure centre** on the other hand, is a building containing a swimming pool and other places where you can play sports. (*Note: This is a very typical British usage, as can be known by the spelling of 'centre'*). Hence it wouldn't seem fit in this context, unless you are actually taking them for swimming practices. [Source of meaning](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/leisure-centre).